# ol3 geometryFunction interaction.Draw add GPS point

Tags: openlayers, openlayers-3

In a project i'm developing we are using the ol.interaction.Draw functionality to draw geometry. The geometryFunction we are using to add a GPS point to the geometry (linestring or polygon). This is accomplished by setting a boolean to add this GPS point. This boolean is set by a button some were in the HTML.

Al works well but the sketch isn't updated untill we move the cursor over the map again. Is there a way to trigger the geometryFunction without moving the cursor over the map?

```
// Interaction
        $scope.interactions.draw = new ol.interaction.Draw({
            source: $scope.vector.getSource(),
            type: (function () {
                var type = 'Point';
                if ($scope.layer.TypeName == 'LineStyle')
                    type = 'LineString';
                if ($scope.layer.TypeName == 'PolygonStyle')
                    type = 'Polygon';
                return type;
            })(),
            geometryFunction: function (coordinates, geometry) {

                if (!_.isUndefined(geometry)) {
                    // Is move to GPS position selected?
                    if ($scope.moveToGpsPosition_) {
                        // GPS position
                        var pos = _geolocation.geolocation.getPosition();
                        // Line
                        if ($scope.layer.TypeName == 'LineStyle')
                            coordinates.splice(coordinates.length - 1, 0, pos);
                        // Polygon
                        if ($scope.layer.TypeName == 'PolygonStyle')
                            coordinates[0].splice(coordinates.length - 2, 0, pos);
                        // Stop move to GPS position
                        $scope.moveToGpsPosition_ = false;
                    }
                    geometry.setCoordinates(coordinates);
                } else {

                    // Detect geometry type
                    if ($scope.layer.TypeName == 'PointStyle')
                        geometry = new ol.geom.Point(coordinates);
                    if ($scope.layer.TypeName == 'LineStyle')
                        geometry = new ol.geom.LineString(coordinates);
                    if ($scope.layer.TypeName == 'PolygonStyle')
                        geometry = new ol.geom.Polygon(coordinates);
                }
                return geometry;
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm having a difficult time replicating your problem but I suspect you can solve it by added one of the following after your `geometry.setCoordinates(coordinates);` line:

`map.updateSize();`
or
`map.render();`